# Fetching data with onMounted hook from API endpoint and url parameter VUE JS 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, async-await, vuejs3

In my Vue JS 3 app, I am using the onMounted hook to load an object from a restful API, using the object id defined in the router in my GET request.
Here's the object view.

folder.vue

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="errorMessage">{{ errorMessage }}</div> -->
        <NavBar :pageTitle="folder.title" />
        <div class="max-w-full md:max-w-7xl lg:max-w-5xl mx-auto mt-6">
            <p class="pl-6 pb-2 font-semibold text-white">Cerca </p>
            <SearchBar />
            <div v-if="folder.documents !== []" class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 py-6">
            <div v-for="document in folder.documents" :key="document.id">
                <RouterLink :to="{ name: 'document', params: { documentId: document.id } }">
                <FancyCard :title="document.title" :text="document.intro" />
                </RouterLink>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div v-if="folder.documents === [] | folder.documents === null">
            <p>Non ci sono documenti, creane uno.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
import { defineComponent, onMounted, onErrorCaptured, ref } from 'vue';
//... all other necessary imports

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Folder',
  components: { NavBar, IconButton, SearchBar, FancyCard },
  setup() {
    const folder= ref<FolderModel | null>(null);
    const router = useRoute();
    const folderId = router.params.folderId as string
    const folderService = useFolderService();
    onMounted(async () => {
        folder.value = await folderService.get(folderId);
    })
    const errorMessage = ref<string | null>(null);
    onErrorCaptured((e: unknown) => {
        errorMessage.value = (e as Error).message;
        return false;
    });
    return { folder, errorMessage };
  }
})
```

and this is my folderService.ts

```
export function useFolderService() {
  return {
    async list(): Promise<Array<FolderModel>> {
      const response = await axios.get<Array<FolderModel>>('myAPIendpoint');
      return response.data;
    },

    async get(folderId: string): Promise<FolderModel> {
      const response = await axios.get<FolderModel>(`myAPIendpoint/${folderId}/`, { params: { status: 'PENDING' }});
      return response.data;
    },
  };
}
```

These below are the warnings and error displayed on the console:

> > (warning) [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function at <Folder onVnodeUnmounted=fn ref=Ref<
> > undefined > > at  at
>
> > (warning) runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue
> > internals bug. Please open an issue at
> > https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue-next at <Folder
> > onVnodeUnmounted=fn ref=Ref< undefined > > at
> >  at
>
> > (error) Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

I am assuming the issue is somewhere in this line:

```js
const folder = (ref < FolderModel) | (null > null);
```

because if I change it and give the folder an initial value, it works as expected, but since I am loading the folder within the onMount lifecycle hook, the above definition should be correct.

On a side note, the same kind of setup used in the listing view where I retrieve all folders works perfectly:

```js
    setup() {
        const folderService = useFolderService()
        const folders = ref<Array<FolderModel> | null>(null);
        onMounted(async () => {
          folders.value = await folderService.list();
        })
        return {
          folders
        };
      }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `but since I am loading the folder within the onMount lifecycle hook, the above definition should be correct` ...what makes you believe that? `onMounted` is called when the component is mounted/rendered fr the first time. So at that point (and some hundreds ms after that) the `folder` ref is still `null` - yet your template is written in a way `folder` could not be `null`

Comment: @MichalLevý you are right, thank you for pointing it out. In your opinion what would be the most vue-friendly way of dealing with this? A simple v-if v-else or maybe switching to Suspense?

Comment: Hide the actual content under a `v-if="!!folder"` or something and add a loading/skelton screen in `v-else` will be the best way to deal with it.

Comment: Both ways are correct. Suspense must be placed in the parent component, `v-if` `v-else` can be handled in component itself. In both cases, postponing the async call to `onMounted` makes no sense. The call should be executed asap - directly in `setup`...